# Why is my Gaussian function giving values out of range?

Tags: matlab, probability

I am trying to plot Gaussian using Matlab. My code is like this.

```
  a=1/(0.1*sqrt(2*3.14))
  y1=a*exp(-1*(((X1-Mu).^2)./(2*(Sigma^2))  ))
  plot(X1,y1)
```

My graph looks like [the image on link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Y2c.jpg)

It is showing correct shape but values at y axis is going up to 4. As per my knowledge Gaussian is a probability distribution function and thus must always return value between 0 and 1.Thus I am apprehensive if my implementation is correct?

Comment: _thus must always return value between 0 and 1._ That's not correct. Its __area__ should be 1

Comment: Since MATLAB is Discrete, you should multiply the `y1` variable by `ts`. ts is the sampling time. for example t = -1:0.001:1, the `0.001` is the sampling time. The amplitude will be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a probability distribution function but it is not required to return value between 0 and 1 everytime. As you can see from the picture below, Gaussian graph depends on **variance** and **mean**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is correct. The gaussian is a probability DENSITY function, which is different from a probability distribution. The former must only be larger or equal than zero but when integrated over the entire range of posible `X1`, the result must be equal to 1.

Probability distributions are the ones whos values must be lower or equal to 1.

As a sidenote. Matlab has both the gaussian probability density and distribution functions builtin as `normpdf` and `normcdf` respectively.